# Simplex outcome does not satisfy conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex

I have a simple maximization problem. 
$\ 7x_1+9x_2+5x_3 => max$

With following constraints:

$\ 3x_1+ 4x_2+ 1.5x_3 <= 100 $

$\ 19x_1+ 12x_2+13x_3 <= 1000 $

$\ 8x_1+ 10x_2+9x_3 <= 500 $

$\ 2x_1+ 3x_2+1.9x_3 <= 75 $

After applying simplex method I receive following solution.

$\ x_1 = 9.45, x_3 = 47.14, d_2 =203.5, d_4 = -33.42 $

With some rounding involved, so it is a little rough. 
However when checking the solution it became apparent that condition number 4 has been broken.

I thought that I made some numerical mistake but online [solver](http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/simplex_online_calculator#) came up with the same solution.

It appears that for some reason the algorithm came up with optimal answer violating one of the conditions, which I though to be impossible.

So either the simplex does not work like I think it does or I made some mistake when defining the constraints.

Anyway I wonder what exactly happened and if there is a way how to prevent it from happening again.

Edit: $\ x_2$ is supposed to be multiplied by 9 in the problem.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake writing the equation. Going to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [this calculator](http://simplexrechner.matthias-priebe.de/start.php?template=projekte/simplex1.php) and its calculation steps are the following:

```
Bas x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  b
x4  3   4   1.5 1               100
x5  19  12  13      1           1000
x6  8   10  9           1       500
x7  2   3   1.9             1   75
F   -7  -9  -5  0   0   0   0   0


Bas x1      x2  x3      x4     x5   x6  x7  b
x2  0.75    1   0.375   0.25    0   0   0   25
x5  10      0   8.5     -3      1   0   0   700
x6  0.5     0   5.25    -2.5    0   1   0   250
x7  -0.25   0   0.775   -0.75   0   0   1   0
F   -0.25   0   -1.625  2.25    0   0   0   225



Basis   x1         x2   x3      x4         x5   x6      x7          b
x2  0.870967741935  1   0   0.612903225806  0   0   -0.483870967742 25
x5  12.7419354839   0   0   5.22580645161   1   0   -10.9677419355  700
x6  2.1935483871    0   0   2.58064516129   0   1   -6.77419354839  250
x3  -0.322580645161 0   1   -0.967741935484 0   0   1.29032258065   0
F   -0.774193548387 0   0   0.677419354839  0   0   2.09677419355   225

Bas x1    x2    x3   x4    x5   x6    x7        b
x1  1   1.148   0   0.704   0   0   -0.556  28.703703
x5  0   -14.630 0   -3.740  1   0   -3.889  334.259
x6  0   -2.519  0   1.037   0   1   -5.556  187.037
x3  0   0.370   1   -0.7407 0   0   1.111   9.259259
F   0   0.888   0   1.2222  0   0   1.667   247.222
```

It satisfies the fourth condition:$2\cdot 28.703703+1.9\cdot 9.259259=74.9999981$

Comment: Ok so it appears that the process goes wrong in the second step. The calculator I used didn't consider $/ b_4 $ to be eligible for the check because it was not positive. The question is: is it possible to perform check on non positive RHS variable?

Comment: @user1561358 What do you mean ? Please be more specific.

Comment: I updated the comment. I hit the enter by accident.

Comment: @user1561358 The simplex rule refers to non-negative $b_i´s$. This is the rule. The rule cannot be changed by anybody.